# Why is the R -tree unordered ? Yet it is said to follow the rules of the B-tree

Tags: database, data-structures, b-tree, spatial-index, r-tree

OK, in the screenshot attached below is an R tree. It has R1 and R2 at the root. to the left of R1 is r3,r3,r5. Why is that? I thought that elements to the left of the root element should be less than. If the root element on the root was R6, then it would have made sense to put R3,R4,R5 on the left. As far as I know so far, B+ and B- trees follow that rule.

Also on the leaf nodes, why is there an empty space after R12 and the likes? I'm confused.

[image]

Comment: Can someone help ?

Answer (score 2):

B-tree and R-tree are based on totally different concepts. There are few things that they have in common: similar names, and high *n*-arity (so that they can be stored in disks with poor random access time).

1. B-tree stores single dimensional values, which are naturally ordered. R-tree stores multidimensional values, which cannot be naturally ordered. (How are you going to order pairs of *x*/*y* coordinates?).
2. B-tree stores elements themselves, while R-tree stores coordinates of artificially constructed bounding boxes. R<sub>i</sub> in image above are just random labels -- you can replace them with whatever names you like.
3. Connections in B-tree and R-tree mean absolutely different relations.

   If some B-tree node stores *n* values, then it has *n*+1 pointers which are located (semantically) *between* adjacent values. If, for example, some pointer is located between values 25 and 70, then it leads to a subtree which is allowed to store elements from 26 to 69. Thus, it can be said that connections in a B-tree mean *in-between* relations.

   If some R-tree node stores *n* bounding boxes coordinates, then it also has *n* pointers to lower level, one per each bounding box. If some pointer belongs to R<sub>i</sub>, then it leads to subtree which contains all inner bounding boxes relative to R<sub>i</sub>. This is kind of "containing" relation.

To understand further difference between B and R trees, you may construct R-tree which stores single dimensional numbers (rectangles are degenerated into line segments) and compare it to B-tree.

So, to answer your first question: R1 is not smaller than R3, R4 or R5. These are just labels of respective rectangles. Instead, R3, R4 and R5 are part of R1.

As of why there is empty space -- this depends on algorithm used to construct tree. Different algorithms and different orders of insertions/deletions may end up with different trees containing the same set of elements. (The same is true for B-trees.)

Comment: So r3,r4,r5 could be placed on the left as well ?  Not mandatory ?

Comment: Gudok, how does insertion and deletion in R tree work ?  The explainations I've seen online are so vague. they don't explain it well in detail.

Comment: Yes. You can't say that Ri is larger than Rj -- there is simply no such relation defined for rectangles. But you can say that Ri is contained in Rj -- that's why R3,R4,R5 are located in subtree with R1 as its root. Think of values inside each node as of *set* and not as of sorted list (as in B-tree). You can easily rearrange R3,R4,R5 to R5,R3,R4 along with their subtrees. Practical impl., of course, will somehow order rectangles inside nodes to speedup search (because typical node may contain thousands of rectangles -- not just 3 as in image above).

Comment: There is no good explanation for insertions and deletions because R-tree is not a well defined structure. Every particular implementation uses different heuristics. Wikipedia briefly mentions well-known heuristics.

Answer (score 0):

Only one-dimensional data is ordered.

The idea of *balancing* and *splitting* of the R-tree is similar to the B-tree; the R-tree similarly ensures a minimum page fill etc. - the concept of *pages* is similar, too.

But while the B-tree uses a *linear* order of nodes, the R-tree uses a bounding volume hierarchy, not a linear order, because multidimensional data is not ordered. There is no "left" or "right" in the R-tree.